# Fetch data from two tables using join and where conditions on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select * from AMEDIAproject_TitleManagement_TitleDetails full 
    outer JOIN AMEDIAproject_TitleManagement_TitleOwner 
    ON AMEDIAproject_TitleManagement_TitleDetails.title_owner_id = 
        AMEDIAproject_TitleManagement_TitleOwner.title_owner_id
where AMEDIAproject_TitleManagement_TitleDetails.title_code=@title_code 
    or (AMEDIAproject_TitleManagement_TitleDetails.title_code is not null)
```

- what I want is if I don't provide the title_code it should return all the data for all title codes but If I specify the title_code it should return data for specify title_code

Answer (score 1):

```
where AMEDIAproject_TitleManagement_TitleDetails.title_code = 
      coalesce(@title_code, AMEDIAproject_TitleManagement_TitleDetails.title_code)
```